# Why is this code for sqrt(x) coding challenge working?

Tags: javascript, arrays, binary-search

I am currently studying binary search so I solved this coding challenge:

Given a non-negative integer x, compute and return the square root of x.

Since the return type is an integer, the decimal digits are truncated, and only the integer part of the result is returned. from leetcode https://leetcode.com/problems/sqrtx/

I used the following code, but I don't understand why in some cases I have to return sqrt-1, and in some other cases just sqrt.

```js
var mySqrt = function(x) {
    let min = 0;
    let max = x;
    let sqrt;
    while(min<=max){
        sqrt = Math.floor((min+max)/2);
        if(sqrt*sqrt == x ){
            return Math.floor(sqrt);
        } else if(sqrt*sqrt < x){
            min = sqrt + 1;
        } else max = sqrt - 1;
    }
  return sqrt*sqrt > x ? sqrt-1: sqrt;
};
```

Comment: For example, the square root of `32` is between 5 and 6. 
Somehow the loop produces `6` for sqrt. But truncation means you should choose 5 rather than 6.

Answer (score 0):

On each iteration, it gets a bit closer to the result. The `min` number will always get higher, and the `max` number will always get lower, and by using those two numbers, a `sqrt` number is also calculated. There are 4 possibilities:

- If `min` matches `max`, there is nowhere further to narrow; you're right at the edge of the square root. So the code does `return sqrt*sqrt > x ? sqrt-1: sqrt;` - if the current `sqrt` produces a value too high, what's returned is `sqrt - 1`, else it returns `sqrt`. One of those values is necessarily the desired result.
- If the calculated `sqrt` is the true square root (`sqrt*sqrt == x`), then it can be returned immediately.
- `if(sqrt*sqrt < x)` indicates that the square root is too small, and so the minimum value should be raised (hence `min = sqrt + 1`)
- The only other possibility is that the square root is too large, and so the maximum value is decremented (hence `max = sqrt - 1`)

Eventually you'll come to a point where either you find an exact match, or you'll be on the edge between deciding on `sqrt` and `sqrt - 1`, and can return the appropriate value.